# How to make a NativeScript switch component’s state (ON/OFF) persist between page/app navigation based on user interaction?

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular

**My problem:**
Currently, I have a switch component I’m fiddling with.
My goal is to be able to click the switch component “ON” and have it stay switched “ON” when I navigate back to the home or another page.

**Attempted solutions & experimentation:**
I attached a method to the native (checkedChanged) event that comes “built-in” with NativeScript switch components.
Passed the built-in (checkedChanged) event, the event data from the switch click.
Then brute forced the switch component’s “checked” attribute, to permanently be TRUE or FALSE in two separate test cases on first user click, regardless of subsequent clicks...but whenever I navigate away from the page the switch in question is reset. I know this because my flag/counter is also reset. Every time I navigate away from the page.
Any tips on how to do this. Say I click a switch “ON” in one page in the app and navigate to another page in the same app. Or close out the app completely is there any way to make the state persist? Meaning that switch stays switched ON or OFF based on human interaction/toggling?

**Resources:**
https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/ui/ng-ui-widgets/switch

Comment: Save the value to a persistent storage (if you want to retain the value even after app is killed / restarted), may be application-settings Or in a global variable and bind the value to the checked property.

Comment: My line of thinking for solving this problem. Is pretty much identical to this suggestion but the real question is how? You mention global variables. Where would they be placed in an Angular/NativeScript app? Since individual components have their own HTML, CSS, and typescript files?

Comment: It's just logical statement. If you put an object within a JavaScript / TypeScript file, export that variable it can be globally imported anywhere and the value is retained. If you are using Angular, it's even easier with a service injected at app module to retain the value. If it's too hard then simply go with [application-settings](https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/ng-framework-modules/application-settings), write the value on checkedChange event, read and on page load.

Comment: tried the service, and applications methods: https://imgur.com/a/SUfI8Qf still nothing

Comment: you can set it by default on or off according to your situation

Answer (score 0):

Use [application-settings](https://docs.nativescript.org/ns-framework-modules/application-settings) to store simple value persistently. There are also options like [nativescript-localstorage](https://github.com/NathanaelA/nativescript-localstorage) / [SQLite](https://github.com/NathanaelA/nativescript-sqlite) for storing data persistently. `application-settings` may be a good choice for simple key value pairs.

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { setBoolean, getBoolean } from "tns-core-modules/application-settings";

@Component({
    selector: "Settings",
    moduleId: module.id,
    template: `
        <ActionBar title="Settings" class="action-bar">
        </ActionBar>

        <GridLayout>
            <ScrollView class="page">
                <StackLayout class="form">
                    <GridLayout columns="*,auto">
                        <Label text="On / Off" class="h2"></Label>
                        <Switch [ngModel]="value" (ngModelChange)="onSwtichChange($event)"></Switch>
                    </GridLayout>
                </StackLayout>
            </ScrollView>
        </GridLayout>
    `
})
export class SettingsComponent {

    value = getBoolean("my-value", false);

    constructor() {
    }

    onSwtichChange(value: boolean) {
        setBoolean("my-value", value);
    }
}
```

[Playground Sample](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=WLl7xc)

Comment: Nice attempt but your code doesn't work (persist the switch state). I played around with get and set boolean myself before I saw your post... no dice. Here's a video testing the code you suggested: https://imgur.com/a/Fj7weGT 
Am I missing something here? Any other suggestions? I'm done with this for Saturday before I get too frustrated will revisit tomorrow enjoy your weekend. Thanks

Comment: Did you even try the Playground link, I'm sure it works. Did you import NativeScriptFormsModule in your module?

Comment: thank you for taking the time out to help. The playground sample you provided works. However, when I try and apply the code in the sample to my project I am not able to replicate the effect. I'm making sure I have the forms and common modules imported like you suggested and even created a module file just like in your example.
My code below:
https://imgur.com/a/9zx6WMK
Been hacking at this for 8+ hours straight. I'm unsure of what to do at this point.